# c, gets(),fgets()

Tags: c

```
char s1[100];
char s2[100];
gets(s1);
fgets(s2,sizeof(s2),stdin);
printf("%d,%d\n",strlen(s1),strlen(s2));
```

after run, I input "abcd" two times,
and the result i got is : `4,5`
why is that?

Comment: From [a `gets` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets): "Never use gets(). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer security. Use fgets() instead."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `gets` / `fgets` man page:

```
 The fgets() function reads at most one less than the number of characters
 specified by n from the given stream and stores them in the string s.
 Reading stops when a newline character is found, at end-of-file or error.
 The newline, if any, is retained.  If any characters are read and there
 is no error, a `\0' character is appended to end the string.

 The gets() function is equivalent to fgets() with an infinite n and a
 stream of stdin, except that the newline character (if any) is not stored
 in the string.  It is the caller's responsibility to ensure that the
 input line, if any, is sufficiently short to fit in the string.
```

`fgets` keeps the newline, which is character number 5, but `gets` doesn't.
Also, get into a habit of using `fgets` always, as it is impossible to prevent buffer overflows when using `gets`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `fgets` returns the string with `'\n'` at the end while `gets` not.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`gets()` man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/fgets.3.html):

> The `gets()` function is equivalent to `fgets()` with an infinite `n` and a `stream` of `stdin`, except that the newline character (if any) is not stored in the string.