# fgets() doesn't retain '\n' for the input of size of array

Tags: c, string, fgets, strlen

I have gone through many posts on SO regarding the preferred use of `fgets()` over `scanf()` and `gets()`.Some referred about the fgets() [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/).

Then there is [this wonderful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810764/c-gets-fgets/4810820#4810820)  showing the number of characters stored by `fgets()` by using `strlen()`.One of the answers on this post mentioned as described in the man page that fgets() retains the `\n`(if any) and that's why the `strlen()` function returns text_size+1. I tried to test it through a program :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define text_size 10
int main(void)
{
  char str[text_size+1];
  fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
  printf("%s",str);
  printf("%d",strlen(str));

     return 0;
}
```

when I input text of size smaller than `text_size` ,the `strlen(str)` returns the value (text_size+1) which is quite understandable to me after reading the man page that it retained the `\n` after text. As for example:-

INPUT: hello

OUTPUT: hello 6 (i guess \n is retained here).

But when I input text of exact size as `text_size` or even larger size the value returned by `strlen(str)` is equal to (text_size) and hence 10 is printed out,I wonder why the `\n` is discarded here?

INPUT: helloworldhi

OUTPUT: helloworld 10(why 11 is not returned here since 1 more character place is still there , i don't understand here which of the characters here has been given preference `\0` or `\n` and why???

I am not pretty sure about all the undefined behavior in C, but can we call it an UB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
```

You specify here the size of your buffer, thus when there is too much text, it will only read in (size - 1) characters, to make room for a null character.

Take a look at [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.

Comment: ok then printf() statement should print text only up to size-1?

Comment: @PHIfounder it should print text up to size - 1 (or rather `text_size`) in your example.

Comment: one thing is not clear which I specially asked the question for, when the text is less than text_size it retains \n value (strlen() returns text_size+1) but not for the text of size greater than or equal to text_size ? why is that behavior observed?

Comment: @PHIfounder it has nothing whatsoever to do with "\n". When your string has enough place, it stores all it can. When it runs out of place, things get dropped. Think of a bag analogy. What happens if you have a bag which can hold 10 balls and you try to place 11? For completeness, imagine that there is one special ball you need to add once the bag is filled( the null terminator), and so you really can only take 9 balls

Comment: NO i think here you may be wrong check the post link which i have provided in the question,it is said that newline character(if any) is added after text and counted as text and that's why the strlen() returns text_size+1 ..... and OK, So , when the string gets larger `fgets()` gives preference to `\0` over `\n`, Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: @PHIfounder yes, it gives priority to `\0` over ALL characters if it has to. Again, nothing to do with `\n`. Remember not inserting \0 is begging for a crash, so it is critical to add it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32402/discussion-between-phifounder-and-karthik-t)

Comment: Note that it isn't quite accurate to say "truncated". If you don't pass a large enough buffer to `fgets()`, only part of the input is read, but the rest remains in the input stream, waiting for you to call `fgets()` again...

Comment: @ElchononEdelson ah I see.